# Pass an array between two sibling components

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So I have 'Home' component that there the user can create QR code. I have a method that create an array of those QR items.
Now I need to pass this array into other component, it's a sibling component and not child-parent/parent-child relation.

I tried to create eventBus but it's not going well.

**App.vue**

```
<template>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <app-header></app-header>
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
      <router-view></router-view>
      </div>
      </div>
</div>

</template>

<script>
import { eventBus } from './main';
import Header from './components/Header.vue';
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      urls: []
    }
  },
  created() {
    eventBus.$on('updateUrls', (data) => {
      this.urls.push(this.data);
    })
  },
  components: {
    'app-header': Header
  }
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

**Home.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h2>Welcome to QR</h2>
        <p>Generate qr codes on your own website</p>
        <hr>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Your website address:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="address">
        </div>
        <a :href="url" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary" :disabled="!address">Generate</a>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" :disabled="!address" @click="saveData">Save</button>
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" @click="clearInput" :disabled="!address">Clear</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import axios from 'axios';
    import { eventBus } from '../main';

    export default {

        data() {
            return {
                address: '',
                prefix: `https://www.qrtag.net/api/qr_4.png?url=`,
            }
        },

        computed: {
            url() {
                const url = this.prefix + this.address;
                return url;
            }
        },
        methods: {
            clearInput() {
                this.address = ''
            },
            saveData() {
                const data = {
                    url: this.url,
                    date: new Date()
                }

                eventBus.$emit('updateUrls', this.data);
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

**History.vue**

```
   <template>
    <div>
        <router-link tag="a" class="nav-link" to="/dashboard">Generate another QR</router-link>
        <p :urls="urls" v-for="link in urls">{{ link.url }}</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { eventBus } from '../main';
    export default {
        props: ["urls"],
        data() {
            return {

            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**main.js**

```
export const eventBus = new Vue();
```

Comment: If you don't want to use Vuex, try *lifting the state up* or use an EventBus

Comment: What is means lifting the state?

Comment: It means to let the *common parent component* of the two sibling components hold the state, then pass the data down as `props`, instead of letting one of the childs hold the data. In this case it means to let the parent of `Home` and `History` hold the *array* instead of `Home` holding it

Comment: To use eventBus I have to create click listener right? I want to pass the data without trigger an event.

Comment: Looks like `Home.vue` and `History.vue` components are rendered by Vue-Router seperately, and only one at the time (obviously). Both components are not rendered at the same time, which makes it really difficult to have a *common parent component* to share data between those two. What's the reason for not using Vuex ?

Comment: I think it's overkill for that purpose, isn't it? Most of time we will use vue-router so I'm wondering how can I use custom event in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the `parent` be the source of truth. What I mean is when a new QR code is created, the child `$emits` the new value to the parent, who then stores it in an array.

Once the parent holds the information it is easy for it to distribute it to all of its children.

Comment: Tried with event bus as I'm using router-view in the parent app. Still not working(edited question).

Comment: Why do you need an event bus? It's a very simple setup. I will try to give you an example

Answer (score 0):

**Try the following snippet:**

```js
Vue.component('home',{
  template: `<div>
    <h2>Home Component</h2>
    <button @click="sendQrCode">Check</button>
  </div>`,
  methods:{
    sendQrCode:function(){
      this.$root.$emit("codeSent",["code1","code2","code3"]);
    }
  }
});

Vue.component('history',{
  template: `<div>
    <h2>History Component</h2>
    {{ codes }}
  </div>`,
  data:function(){
    return {
      codes:null
    }
  },
  created(){
    let that = this;
    this.$root.$on("codeSent",(payload)=>{
      that.codes = payload;
    })
  }
  
});

new Vue({
  el:"#app"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>

<html>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <home></home>
      <hr />
      <history></history>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm using router-view to render the components so that won't work.

Comment: Okay, then what's the reason to not use Vuex?

Comment: I finally used it and it works just fine but I thought that is an overkill for my needs.